# Entry boxes don't give results

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

```
from tkinter import *
import os
os.system ("clear") 

root = Tk()
root.title('Test')
root.geometry('1000x600')

def submit():
    submit_text = Label(text=(eq))
    submit_text.pack()



label = Label(root, text='Enter the first mounth')
label.pack()

textbox3 = Entry(root, width=30)
textbox3.pack()

textbox2 = Entry(root, width=30)
textbox2.pack()

textbox1 = Entry(root, width=30)
textbox1.pack()

eq = textbox1.get() + textbox2.get() + textbox3.get()

button = Button(root, text="submit", command=submit)
button.pack()



root.mainloop()
```

I want the code to open up a window and I'm going to put 3 numbers and I want the code to add the 3 numbers and show me the result when II press the button, but it does nothing.

Comment: You are calling `.get()` on your Entries *immediately after creating them*.  They contain nothing yet, of course.  You need to do that inside `submit()`.

Comment: Im new to coding so i dont know hot to do that

Comment: You need to learn about "event-driven programming".  When you call those TK functions to create widgets, nothing actually gets drawn.  All those calls do is queue up messages to be handled later.  Nothing happens until you get to `mainloop`, which then handles and dispatches messages.  In your case, you need to move that `eq =` line into the `submit` function, so you don't try to fetch the values until the button has been hit.